# python dict key in list to filter - python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

```
a = [{"price": 1,"id": 1},{"price": 8.2, "id": 2}, {"price": 10.99,"id": 3}]

user = ['price', 'abc']
```

output supposed to be:

```
output = [{"price": 1},{"price": 8.2}, {"price": 10.99}]
```

The scenario is that *dict a* keys should be filtered by *user* list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a set intersection operation to get the keys to retain:

```py
result = [{k: d[k] for k in set(d.keys()).intersection(set(user))} for d in a]
print(result)
```

This prints:

```py
[{'price': 1}, {'price': 8.2}, {'price': 10.99}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension

```
[{u: val_a.get(u) for u in user if val_a.get(u)} for val_a in a]
```

Nested comprehensions may not be desirable and the above example checks twice for the value.  Building your results by a loop may give the most straightforward result and be readable at the same time:

```
results = []
for val_a in a:
    result = {}
    for u in user:
        u_val = val_a.get(u)
        if u_val:
            result.update({u: u_val})
    results.append(result)
```

Python3.8+:

```
results = []
for val_a in a:
    result = {}
    for u in user:
        if u_val := val_a.get(u)
            result.update({u: u_val})
    results.append(result)
```